# Loss in performance when moving from clustered composite key to sequential integer clustered key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have a table with primary key (primkey) composed of *(USER_NAME VARCHAR(50), AGE INT, DATE DATETIME)*. This then indexes a bunch of data for the user on this particular day. In general, I would request all data for a *USER_NAME*.

Correct me if I am wrong - the clustering here works well because it will first cluster based on *USER_NAME* so will lay out all data for *USER_NAME=JOHN_SMITH* physically close together. Then it will cluster based on *AGE* etc. Because I request all data for a particular user this should mean IO is optimised, that is I read least amount of pages and the query, which requests a large amount of data and is thus IO bound is fastest.

I am currently planning to replace the *(USER_NAME, AGE)* with a uid which while a sequentially incrementing number is a random mapping between *(USER_NAME,AGE)* and the uid. This will of course also alter the primkey to be *(UID INT,DATE DATETIME)* Because the uid is just a number, e.g. (JOHN_SMITH,24) might be 123124 and *(JOHN_SMITH,25)* might turn out to be 352431, clustering becomes pointless as far as I can see. What I mean is that while *(JOHN_SMITH,24)* and *(JOHN_SMITH,25)* in the old primkey are clearly data for the same user in 2 sequential years and the DB will cluster the data close together on disk, the numbers 123124 and 352431 do not hold any information about the referenced data. That is the old primkey had structure to it, the new one has no structure and no implicit information about the referenced data.

One solution is to implement some sort of an addressing scheme into the UID (e.g. IPv4 style but a lot simpler) - that is every USER_NAME gets a reserved space of 150 UIDs, that is if JOHN_SMITH gets UID of 0, JOHN_SM**Y**TH will get UID of 150 at least and 0-149 is reserved for *(USER_NAME=JOHN_SMITH, AGE=?)* combinations.

I don't physically want to go down an addressing scheme. Any thoughts on this (incl. if my theory is correct) will be appreciated.

1. I'm performance constraint on SELECT, don't particularly care about INSERT and DELETE.
2. The Users table is very large (tens of GBs).

EDIT: Example of a SELECT query (the values is likely going to be a lot longer list, not just 2 elements.

```
     DECLARE @testtable TABLE 
     (
     uid INT,
     startdate DATETIME,
     enddate DATETIME
     );
     INSERT INTO @testtable
     (
     uid,
     startdate,
     enddate
     )
     VALUES
     (1233890,'01-Jul-2017 00:00:00','15-Jul-2017 23:59:59'),
     (1523420,'01-Jul-2018 00:00:00','15-Jul-2018 23:59:59')

     SELECT UID, [DATE], [WAKEUP_TIME] 
     FROM dbo.USERS user 
     INNER JOIN @testtable cont 
     ON user.uid = cont.uid 
     AND user.DATE >= cont.startdate 
     AND user.DATE <= cont.enddate
     WHERE user.USER_NAME = 'John'
     ORDER BY 2 ;
```

Comment: What are the important select queries that should remain fast?

Comment: @usr See amendment in original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be filtering by equality on `USER_NAME,AGE` and by range on `DATE`. If you replace `USER_NAME,AGE` by a new artifical value `uid` then the index seek based on equality filtering would still work.

From the query that you posted it seems that SQL Server will likely execute it by repeatedly probing into the `USERS`. Once for each item in `@testtable`. This is done as a nested loop join.

It's the same index usage pattern and query plan shape. But you are correct in that different values of `AGE` will now be spread across the index essentially randomly whereas before all `AGE` values for the same user were colocated.

This can definitely make for a performance loss by causing more disk seeks. You indicated that most of the table will not be cached in RAM. Therefore, the number of points in the index that must be accessed is important for performance (as you correctly identified).

The simplest solution of course is to not adopt new `uid` column. But I assume you have reasons for doing that.

You could implement a simple "addressing scheme" by redundantly packing the `AGE` value into the last byte (e.g. `db_uid = sequential_id_for_user_name * 256 + AGE`). You need to take care not to overflow.

This would physically pack together related `AGE` values and might well result in a speedup.

Also consider using a `bigint` to have more space to encode data.

Answer (score 0):

First, the losses that you are speculating about for `select` queries are gains for `insert`s and `delete`s.  New records are simply appended at the "end" of the table, with no page splits.

Second -- if you can -- you might want to try the new structure.  If the entire table fits into memory, for instance, then reading data from multiple pages versus a single page is not going to make that much of a difference.

Finally, SQL Server does not require that the primary key be used for clustering.  You only have one clustering key.  But you can introduce a new unique id, make it the primary key, and still cluster by other columns.

Comment: Thanks - (1) I'm performance constraint on SELECT, don't particularly care about INSERT and DELETE. (2) The table is very large (tens of GBs). (3) I know - I've used a clustered index as well. Regardless if the query key is a primkey or not (e.g. index), what are your thoughts on the performance standoff above?